# create a project site from the free template SP2016 On-premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom, sub-site, template

I want to create a subsite from a template that I have uploaded as it's shown
[image: here:]

But in my case, I didn’t find the **Custom** tab under Select a template.I find just **Publishing** tab.
[image: here]

I want to know if Custom template is just found in SP Online

Comment: Hi, so you created template on SPO and you want to use it in SP16?

Comment: no I have uploaded  a free template in SP16  and I want to make a subsite from it but I didn't find custom tab, I'm following a tuturial I said maybe bcz in the tutorial they are using Sharepoint online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF37EXDmpLE)

Comment: Make sure you have chosen the correct language, because some templates are based on language in which they were created. Other thing can be that is not compatible for SP2016?

Comment: I chose the version of SP2016, I'm using a trial version. the problem that I don't  have the same choices in Select a template (in the tutorial he has "Collaboration,Entreprise,Custom" but me I have "Publishing")

Comment: Its because you have trial version i think.